# Customized horizontal line

Tags: color, rules, alignment

I am trying to attain the following style of customized horizontal rule for my document.

[image]

I tried the following LATEX code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\\
{\color{gray} \rule{4.85 cm}{2 pt}}\  {\color{lightgray} \rule{\linewidth}{2 pt}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This gives the following satisfying result but I am unable to break the rule from crossing the line width. How to solve this issue? Is there any other way to get this type of horizontal rule?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,calc}
\newlength{\spacelength}
\setlength{\spacelength}{\widthof{\ }}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1]\\
   {\color{gray} \rule{4.85 cm}{2 pt}}\  {\color{lightgray} \rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.85cm-\spacelength\relax}{2 pt}}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The problem is that you wanted

- a rule of 4.85cm
- a space
- and a rule of `\linewidth`.
  This is of course more than one line, so you have to shorten the last line. You want it to have `\linewidth - 2.85cm - WidthOfASpace`. You can calculate this length simply by typing `\dimexpr WhatYouWantToCalculate \relax`. To get the width of a space, I used `\widthof` from the `calc`-package.

I added the showframe-option to `geometry` just to show that the line has now the perfect length, you can remove it without breaking anything.